# Creating an image Gallery with next and previous buttons in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to the development of Swift. I've done several courses but I have some questions that I can't find.

I want to design an application that has 50 or more images, with a previous and next button to go through them in a matrix.

I've looked at random snippets of sample code, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it. What's the easiest and most efficient method to go back and forth between these images in a view? The other problem I have is that I want to be able to save the image when it is selected.

Surely the answer to this is easy for you, but I'm a beginner, and I can't find a solution, after two days of searching and trying.

Thanks in advance!

Finotoni

Comment: Do you want to use iPhone photo library images? or those 50 images will be provided as assets? This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QS2mWk3fAWc) will give an overview. Let me know it helps?

Comment: You can use the collection view . and then when you press the next or previous button you have ti change the index... Or you can use UIPageController as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to use the iPhone photo library. I want to use photos from the app

Comment: I don't want to use the UIPageController. I want to use an image gallery with two arrows, back and next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some steps you need to do:

1. Get/ define your images
2. Have methods (or another way) of getting the previous and next image
3. Displaying the current image

Here is an really easy example that should help you understand:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Your images
    @State var images = ["image1", "image2", "image3"]
    
    // Some indicator on what image is the current one
    @State var imageIndicator: Int = 0
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            // Prev one
            Button(action: {
                // Call a method that gets you the previous image
                if self.imageIndicator == 0 {
                    self.imageIndicator = self.images.count - 1
                } else {
                    self.imageIndicator = self.imageIndicator - 1
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
            }
            
            // Image with indicator to what image to display
            Image(self.images[self.imageIndicator]).resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            // Next one
            Button(action: {
                // Call a method that gets you the next image
                
                if self.imageIndicator == self.images.count - 1 {
                    self.imageIndicator = 0
                } else {
                    self.imageIndicator = self.imageIndicator + 1
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this:

[image]